# ¿Como hago que selenium Webdriver siga funcionando despues de un error TimeOut en python. Usando chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Al iniciar webdriver defino el timeout `driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)`
pero cuando la pagina lanza un error `timeout` ya no puedo navegar por webdriver. no funciona ningun comando aunque el navegador continua ejecutandose.

Soy nuevo utilizando selenium webdriver, si me podrian ayudar.

*** Edición ***
Utilizando el siguiente código.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

urls = ["https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python",
        "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++",
        "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust"
        ]

for url in urls:
    print(f'Cargando "{url}"')
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except TimeoutException: 
        # Qué hacer si se produce la excepción
        print(f'Tiempo de espera agotado cargando la página "{url}" ')
    else:
        # Qué hacer si no se produce la excepción
        link = (driver.find_element_by_class_name("question-hyperlink")
                      .get_attribute('href'))
        print(f"Enlace a pregunta: {link}")
    finally:
        # Qué hacer siempre, se produzca o no la excepción
        driver.delete_all_cookies()

driver.quit()
```

Chromedriver se cuelga cuando ocurre el error de `timeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mediante el método de clase [`set_page_load_timeout`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=set_page_load_timeout#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) puedes especificar el tiempo a esperar mientras una página se está cargando **antes de lanzar una excepción `TimeOutException`**.

Como cualquier excepción no manejada, **ocasiona la inmediata terminación de la ejecución** del hilo en el que se produce, por lo que nada a partir de ese punto en tu código va a ejecutarse. El navegador sigue ejecutándose porque es otro proceso  y no se le envía ninguna orden explícitamente para que dicho proceso termine (`driver.close()` / `driver.quit()`).

Primero debes plantearte si necesitas realmente establecer este timeout y si 10 es un valor razonable para tu caso concreto. Por lo pronto, por la propia esencia de la pregunta, lo que no quieres es lanzar la excepción cuando se produzca esta situación.

Para evitar que la ejecución termine de producirse la excepción, puedes proceder como con cualquier excepción en Python, manejarla con un bloque [`try-except-else-finally`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions). Para ello debes englobar cualquier código susceptible de producir dicho timeout en el bloque `try-except`, en esencia las llamadas a `driver.get`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)

url = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python"

try:
    driver.get(url)

except TimeoutException: 
    print(f'Tiempo de espera agotado cargando la página "{url}" ')
```

En este caso solo se imprime un mensaje por la salida estándar cuando el tiempo de espera se supera, pero debes plantearte que quieres que pase en tu caso concreto (logging, recargar la página, limpiar cookies y cargar otra página, etc)

**Edición**

Si se quiere cargar otra página si el tiempo de espera se consume, suponiendo que tenemos un iterable con las distintas urls un patrón general que se puede usar sería:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

urls = ["https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python",
        "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++",
        "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust"
        ]

for url in urls:
    print(f'Cargando "{url}"')
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except TimeoutException: 
        # Qué hacer si se produce la excepción
        print(f'Tiempo de espera agotado cargando la página "{url}" ')
    else:
        # Qué hacer si no se produce la excepción
        link = (driver.find_element_by_class_name("question-hyperlink")
                      .get_attribute('href'))
        print(f"Enlace a pregunta: {link}")
    finally:
        # Qué hacer siempre, se produzca o no la excepción
        driver.delete_all_cookies()

driver.quit()
```

El webdriver que se use no importa mientras implemente `page_load_timeout`, tanto Firefox, Chrome como Edge lo implementan a día de hoy.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo que quiero hacer despues de que ocurra el timeout es volver a cargar otra pagina. Para no cerrar y abrir nuevamente chromedriver..

Comment: En ese caso asignar el tiempo de espera máximo para la carga y manejar la excepción es la forma simple de hacerlo efectivamente. He editado la pregunta añadiendo un ejemplo real algo más completo a modo de modelo por si sirve de algo, obviamente dependiendo de como obtengas las distintas urls el tipo de ciclo puede variar. Un saludo.

Comment: Voy a probar el codigo con ejemplo que me diste. Si surge mas problemas voy a subir mi código aquí para que lo veas. Muchas Gracias

Comment: @RolandoRojas si tienes un problema relacionado con la pregunta o mi respuesta usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/274704/edit) de debajo de tu pregunta y añade a ella el nuevo código (en los comentarios perdemos el formato del código). No elimines lo que ya hay en la pregunta para que las respuestas y comentarios no queden sin contexto). Deja un mensaje en esta respuesta o en tu pregunta usando @FJSevilla para que sea notificado, sino no me entero XD. Si tienes un problema que no esté  relacionado directamente con `get` y el `timeout` crea otra pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: esta bien gracias XD.

Comment: probe el codigo que me pasaste.. Cuando ocurrió el error de timeout  al volver buscar la siguiente url. chromedriver no ejecuta el comando,ni muestra ningun error.